# How to copy previous column into column with NULL values SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, case

Good day! I have a table, which uses foreign key to build a geographical hierarchy. So using joins, I've made a hierarchy, but some rows don't have a hierarchy levels, and I have to copy previous column values into the cell with NULL value.

The hierarchy goes like this:

Name1             |  Type1              |  Name2     |  Type2    |   Name3      | Type3  | Name4      | Type4  | Name5      | Type5

Far Eastern|  federal district  |  Amur |  area |   Belogorsk | City| Belogorsk | City| Belogorsk | City

This is how it should look like, if there is no Name4/Type4 and Name5/Type5 values, as you see, Name3/Type3 values are copied into next columns. My query is like this, and I have no idea what should I do next.

```
select A.Name as Name1, A.Type as Type1, 
CAST(CASE when B.Name is null then A.Name else B.Name end AS nvarchar) as Name2, 
CAST(CASE when B.Type is null then A.Type else B.Type end AS nvarchar) AS Type2, 
CAST(CASE when C.Name is null then B.Name else C.Name end AS nvarchar) as Name3,
CAST(CASE when C.Type is null then B.Type else C.Type end AS nvarchar) as Type3,
CAST(CASE when D.Name is null then C.Name else D.Name end AS nvarchar) as Name4,
CAST(CASE when D.Type is null then C.Type else D.Type end AS nvarchar) as Type4,
CAST(CASE when E.Name is null then D.Name else E.Name end AS nvarchar) as Name5,
CAST(CASE when E.Type is null then D.Type else E.Type end AS nvarchar) as Type5
from [dbo].[DIM_Geography] AS A
left join [dbo].[DIM_Geography] AS B
on A.ID = B.ParentID
left join [dbo].[DIM_Geography] AS C
on B.ID = C.ParentID
left join [dbo].[DIM_Geography] AS D
on C.ID = D.ParentID
left join [dbo].[DIM_Geography] AS E
on D.ID = E.ParentID;
```

Also I've attached the table structure in the image.

[image: 1]

Comment: Is there a way to identify the base id of the hierarchy?  F.e. similar situations have a base id with a NULL parent_id.

Answer (score 0):

If you can identify the id's to start, then you could use a recursive CTE.
Then pivot the results.

Example:

```
;with RCTE as  (
  -- the seed query to start the recursion
  select ID, parentID,  Name, [Type]
  , 1 as lvl
  , ID as baseID
  from [dbo].[DIM_Geography]
  where parentID is null

  union all

  -- the recursion, where the CTE uses itself
  select t.ID, t.parentID,  t.Name, t.[Type]
  , c.lvl + 1
  , c.baseID
  from RCTE c
  join [dbo].[DIM_Geography] t
    on t.parentID = c.ID
  where c.lvl < 5
)
select 
  max(case when lvl=1 then Name else '' end) as Name1
, max(case when lvl=1 then [Type] else '' end) as Type1
, max(case when lvl=2 then Name else '' end) as Name2
, max(case when lvl=2 then [Type] else '' end) as Type2
, max(case when lvl=3 then Name else '' end) as Name3
, max(case when lvl=3 then [Type] else '' end) as Type3
, max(case when lvl=4 then Name else '' end) as Name4
, max(case when lvl=4 then [Type] else '' end) as Type4
, max(case when lvl=5 then Name else '' end) as Name5
, max(case when lvl=5 then [Type] else '' end) as Type5
from RCTE
group by baseID;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=39ee799197862f489d3cf8103b3ba773)*